# Sharepoint 2013 - Approval Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow

I am not familiar with the approval workflows used within SP2013.
I am able to create the workflows without a problem - what I would like to know is how to customize the modal which the assigned person has to view as well as customizing the email the assigned person receives via SP.
I also have another issue with it the email which is received shows 3 dot points - the third reads:

> 3. Use the **Open this task** button to mark the task as completed. (If you cannot update this task, you might not have access to it.)

I do not know where this Open this task exists  - couldn't see it.
Your direction and help would be appreciated.

First issue - buttons names I am not able to change - some help if you know:
[image: Workflow buttons]

[image: Workflow Buttons]

Second issue - where do I find **Open this task** - I cannot see it

[image: Workflow Email]

Comment: do we talk about approval workflow WITHOUT sharepoint designer like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2aiRFkyN64 ? If so which template do you select when you create it?

Comment: Approval template SP2010 - SharePoint 2010 Platform

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for what I need.
I have used SharePoint designer and edited the  Approval_xxxxx_x_xxxxx.xsn updating the text of the buttons here.
As for the **Open this Task** I have found this under my workflow > then **Start Approval process on**...>click on **Approval** > **Change behavior of a Single Task**>**When a Task is Pending**>see image attached > **then Email task...Current Task: Assign to** > to edit the text.

[image: Workflow - Change email message]